# Create an Athena table with Lambda function node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a function in Lambda (node.js) that will create a table in Athena.

I followed the "Start Query Execution" aws documentation (code attached) but when I run the code I dont see any table being created and there is no error from the function...

Would really appreciate the help with:

- Is it possible that lambda will create a table (just as a query)?
- Is it important that both Lambda function and Athena region will be the 
  same?
- Is there anything wrong in the code?
- Should I use a `.promise()` or `try & catch`?

I have tried to run it in different regions and let Lambda full access to both Athena and S3

```
// console.log('Loading function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

var athena = new AWS.Athena();

var params = {
   "QueryExecutionContext": { 
      "Database": "mydatabase"
   },
   "QueryString": "CREATE TABLE table_test AS SELECT * FROM mydatabase.exsistingtable WHERE time > to_iso8601(current_timestamp - interval '1' day);",
   "ResultConfiguration": { 
      "EncryptionConfiguration": { 
         "EncryptionOption": "SSE-S3" },
      "OutputLocation": "s3://aws-athena-query-results-maybucket-eu-west-1/"
   }
  };
  athena.startQueryExecution(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });

       console.log("end script");

    return "";
};
```

Here is my **IAM policy**:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- CloudWatchFullAccess
- AmazonAthenaFullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
- CloudWatchEventsFullAccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating the table from the result of a query the query first needs to run before the table is created. The `StartQueryExecution` API only starts a query, the query then runs asynchronously and you will have to ask Athena periodically using `GetQueryExecution` whether it is done or not.

Queries can potentially take a lot of time to run, and CTAS operations (Create Table AS), take even longer. You don't want to run your Lambda function while Athena is working, that will just cost you money, and if the query runs for longer than the function's timeout it won't even work.

You can start the query execution in a Lambda function like you do, but if you want to wait for the query to complete and the table to be created you somehow need to run code periodically until `GetQueryExecution` indicates that the query is done.

This can be done with for example Step Functions, where you can have one Lambda function that starts the query, another that polls for completion that is called over and over again, and a final Lambda function that wraps things up, for example. There are good templates in Step Functions for this kind of process.

Answer (score 0):

Thx! Theo
For the quick response...
Just a small question:
After i run the Lambda code (the table which the CATS shouldn't i see that a table has been created in Athena?
Because i dornt see any thing that happend...
:-(

Comment: The table will be created when the query finishes, if you don't see the table there are two possibilities: 1) the query is still running, or 2) the query failed. Use the `GetQueryExecution` API call to see if it is still running (the query execution ID should have been logged by your Lambda function). You can also use AWS CLI to check the query: `aws athena get-query-execution --region THE_REGION --query-execution-id QUERY_ID`